# Mock integration test external request in CakePHP 3

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

We are using CakePHP 3.3

In a integration test, if a request is sent out to an external site inside the tested action, is there anyway for us to mock that request?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what HTTP client library you are using. Guzzle allows you to mock requests.

http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/testing/unit-testing.html

Comment: We are using CakePHP 3.3 in this case. And the controller extends from Cake's Integration Test

Comment: Yes, but what HTTP client library are you using to make the external request with?

Comment: You are right! Guess I am trying to think too much in this case.Accepting your answer now.